# Apache Camel Exception. Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I receive an xml message from the queue:

```
<v1:ct_ChangeDateRequest xmlns:v1="http://www.sm.ru/phone/apptypes/ChangeDate/v1">
  <v1:Name>string</v1:Name>
  <v1:getNewDate>3</v1:getNewDate>

  <v1:Channel>string</v1:Channel>

  <v1:CarNumber>1000.00</v1:CarNumber>
</v1:ct_ChangeDateRequest>
```

In Spring context, I'm trying to put a message to a stored procedure:

```
<unmarshal ref="jaxb"/>
            <setHeader headerName="setnewdate">
                <simple>${in.body.getName().getNewDate().getChannel().getCarNumber()}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="storedproc:dataSource?procedureName={{setNewDate}}"/>
```

And I catch this exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: getNewDate() not found on bean: string of type: java.lang.String.

UPD:
I added class with apache exchange:

```
public CtChangeDateRequest process(CtChangeDateRequest request, Exchange exchange) {

        final CtChangeDateRequest response = new CtChangeDateRequest();

        exchange.getOut().setHeader("iName", request.getName());
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("iNewDate", request.getNewDate());
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("iChannel", request.getChannel());
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("iCarNumber",request.getCarNumber());

        log.info("Headers for storedproc was filled. Name: {}, NewDate {},Channel {}, CarNumber {},", request.getName(),
                request.getNewDate(),request.getChannel(),request.getCarNumber());
        return response;
```

and bean in spring context:

```
 <bean id="changeDateRequestProcessor"
          class="ru.phone.ChangeDateRequestProcessor"/>
```

.
.
.

```
<to uri="storedproc:dataSource?procedureName={{setStatementDate}}"/>
            <bean ref="changeDateRequestProcessor"/>
```

and now catch:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedHashMap to the required type: ru.phone.apptypes.changetdate.v1.CtChangeDateRequest with value {}

UPD2: 
I solved this problem. it was a stupid mistake: 
I set bean(where storedproc was filled) after the procedure instead of before. Need to swap:

```
 <bean ref="changeDateRequestProcessor"/>
   <to uri="storedproc:dataSource?procedureName={{setStatementDate}}"/>
```

Comment: in.body.getName() returns a string and there is no getNewDate() method in the String class.

Comment: I know, but then how do I process the message in <simple>?

Comment: have you tried something along the line `<xpath>//CarNumber</xpath>`? Next, your sample does not make much sense IMO. For the given XML `Name`, `getNewDate`, `Channel` and `CarNumber` are siblings and not in a parent/child relationship and I also don't think that `1000.00`is the procedureName you want to invoke on the dataSource either

Comment: I don't think that 1000 is procedureName. Why did you decide so?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. `?procedureName={{setNewDate}}` is basically some injected property value and not the header value extracted. What should the request and response classes do? Are they JAXB or Jackson annotated in some way? The error simply tells you that it can't convert the LinkedHashMap to your new request class. You either can [teach Camel how to convert the data](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html) or [use some common data formats](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html) Camel already knows how to map

Comment: Roman,thanks for the answer.  I solved this problem

Comment: @bardir16 "Roman,thanks for the answer. I solved this problem" When you solved your problem then post the solution as an answer to also help others...